# TextInputLayout change color on button click

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am having trouble changing the color of my TextInputLayout underline. Does anyone know how to change it 'On Click? it goes like this like..
onClick
if ( is true ) {
change textinputlayout underline color into red
} else {
non 
}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new style like this in your styles.xml TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout, you then need to add `colorControlActivated` and `colorControlHighlight`.

```
 <style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"     
parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_13sdp</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>

        //added attributes
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    </style>
```

and change your color accordingly and use it here in styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

- `android:textColorHint="#FF0000"` was EditText's hint color.
- You can change `android:textColor="#FF0000"` in the `EditText` as text color.
- You can add `app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"` to change the error text color.

And like this .

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textColorHint="#FF0000"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_error_hint_Style"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
    app:errorEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.@0123456789"
        android:hint="email / snipe id"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textColorHint="@color/primary"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The  `LEFT-TOP` hint color depended on `app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"`.

And the style code:

```
<style name="text_in_layout_hint_Style">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Add error text style

```
 <style name="text_in_layout_error_hint_Style">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

like this:
[image]

Comment: does this make my underline makes red as well?

Comment: When it focus ,it will be red .

Comment: I see.. but.. I only want it to turn red when the user pressed submit without typing text in it. and once the user typed I want it to go back to its normal color. is that feasible sir?